# Make PyCharm successfully run session.get() from requests_html

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm

I am trying to web scrape with python in PyCharm using requests_html. The following code doesn't return an error in the terminal using the same venv as my PyCharm project (python 3.8.10), but when I use PyCharm I get an error.

The code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession
response = session.get('https://python.org')
```

After running `response = session.get('https://python.org')` in PyCharm I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

How can I make PyCharm successfully run `session.get()`?

Comment: Assuming you've done all the checking that your pycharm environment is indeed the same as what you're using in terminal...  How are you executing the script in Pycharm? Any special parameters or environmental variables set in pycharm?  Are you running debug or regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally left out the parentheses here:

`session = HTMLSession`

So: `session.get` --> `<function Session.get at 0x10377e550>`.

`help(session.get)` --> `get(self, url, **kwargs)`.

It's trying to call the `get()` method on a class HTMLSession rather than an instance of the class, that is, a session. In that case, the function receives the string argument in place of the implicit `self` argument and it doesn't receive the `url` argument.

Whereas after:

`session = HTMLSession()`

`session.get` --> `<bound method Session.get of <requests_html.HTMLSession object at 0x10276c460>>`

`help(session.get)` --> `get(url, **kwargs)`.

`session.get('https://python.org')` --> `<Response [200]>`.